# Executing Sh with xdotools commands from PHP

Tags: php, linux, shell, xdotool

I'm trying to execute a sh script that it's using inside xdotool commands, this is invoked from a PHP page.

The user that is executing apache is "daemon".

SH Code

```
echo $1
win=`xdotool search --onlyvisible --name Zoiper windowactivate`
whoami
sleep 2
xdotool $win type $1
key Return
sleep 10
xdotool key alt+h
```

PHP Code

```
<?php
    shell_exec("sudo sh /tmp/zoiper_dialer.sh " . $phone);
?>
```

Comment: What's the problem? Can You log as deamon end execute this command?

Comment: Is `DISPLAY` set correctly? Does the user running this php script have permission to do things with that display?

Comment: You didn't really describe what your exact problem is, so this is just a wild guess: Is it possible that your *daemon* user does not have sudo privileges to execute that command?

Comment: I guess `$phone` is defined somewhere above the given line?

Comment: Try `shell_exec("DISPLAY=:0 sudo sh /tmp/zoiper_dialer.sh " . $phone);`

Comment: How the hell could I mark this as answered???